# Copy an array backwards? Array.Copy?

Tags: c#, arrays, copy, reverse

I have a `List<T>` that I want to be able to copy to an array backwards, meaning start from `List.Count` and copy maybe 5 items starting at the end of the list and working its way backwards. I could do this with a simple reverse `for` loop; however there is probably a faster/more efficient way of doing this so I thought I should ask. Can I use `Array.Copy` somehow?

Originally I was using a `Queue` as that pops it off in the correct order I need, but I now need to pop off multiple items at once into an array and I thought a list would be faster.

Comment: " so i thought a list would be faster." - have you measured a performance problem? If not, you are prematurely micro-optimising...

Comment: and premature optimization is the root of all evil (Knuth)

Comment: nope but using a queue i can only pop one off at a time, but with a list i can do a range, which in most cases is faster.

Comment: Actually, operating on a range isn't faster, unless you're adding to a `List<T>` (because of `Capacity`)

Comment: So your saying a simple for loops is the same speed as Array.Copy? Pretty sure Array.Copy is the fastest c# method there is to copy a group of items from one collection to another

Comment: @daniel: Perhaps, but by a _very_ small margin.  (Unless the aray is very large)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `Array.Reverse` has native code for reversing an array which sometimes doesn't apply and would fall back to using a simple for loop. In my testing `Array.Reverse` is very slightly faster than a simple for loop.  In this test of reversing a 1,000,000 element array 1,000 times, `Array.Reverse` is about 600ms whereas a for-loop is about 800ms.

I wouldn't recommend performance as a reason to use `Array.Reverse` though.  It's a very minor difference which you'll lose the minute you load it into a `List` which will loop through the array again.  Regardless, you shouldn't worry about performance until you've profiled your app and identified the performance bottlenecks.

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        var a = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToArray();

        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {
            Array.Reverse(a);
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Array.Reverse: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            MyReverse(a);
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed MyReverse: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    private static void MyReverse(int[] a)
    {
        int j = a.Length - 1;
        for(int i=0; i<j; i++, j--)
        {
            int z = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = z;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have identified it as a huge performance bottleneck. Currently we are pulling out one result and committing it to a database one at a time, but i'm going to make it commit a range at a time, but it needs to be in order. That is why i am doing it.

Comment: @daniel, but I assume the bottleneck is executing one query against the database at a time, not reversing the array.

Comment: true, wasn't thinking straight xD

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this faster than a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it any number of ways, but the fastest way is get the elements in exactly the manner you are. You can use Array.Reverse, Array.Copy, etc., or you can use LINQ and extension methods, and both are valid alternatives, but they shouldn't be any faster.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your comments:

> Currently we are pulling out one result and committing it to a database one at a time

There is a **big difference** between using a `for` loop to iterate backwards over a `List<T>` and committing records to a database one at a time. The former is fine; nobody's endorsing the latter.

Why not just iterate first--to populate an array--and then send that *array* into the database, all populated?

```
var myArray = new T[numItemsYouWantToSend];

int arrayIndex = 0;
for (int i = myList.Count - 1; arrayIndex < myArray.Length; --i) {
    if (i < 0) break;
    myArray[arrayIndex++] = myList[i];
}

UpdateDatabase(myArray);
```