# How to reverse the order of a byte array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

How do you reverse the order of a byte array in c#?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could use the `Array.Reverse` method:

```
byte[] bytes = GetTheBytes();
Array.Reverse(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Or, you could always use LINQ and do:

```
byte[] bytes = GetTheBytes();
byte[] reversed = bytes.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Array.Reverse(byteArray);
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use the [linq method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx): `MyBytes.Reverse()` as well as the `Array.Reverse()` method.
Which one you should use depends on your needs.

The main thing to be aware of is that the linq version will NOT change your original.  the Array version will change your original array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Array.Reverse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Array.Reverse. Also please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710899/copy-an-array-backwards-array-copy) for more information.