# Converting IEEE 754 float to hex string

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code that converts hex to float i basically need the reverse of this operation

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x445F4002);
float myFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
MessageBox.Show(myFloat.ToString());
```

I want to enter the float and turn it to hex string.

Comment: The answer here is 893.0001

Answer (score 3):

1. Call [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhwsaf3w.aspx) to get a byte array representing your float.
2. Convert the byte array to hex string: [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

FWIW, the code in your question does not do the reverse of this. In fact the code in your question does not receive a hex string. It receives an int literal that you expressed as hex. If you wish to convert from a hex string to a float then you use the code in the link above to convert from hex string to byte array. And then you pass that byte array to `BitConverter.ToSingle`.

---

It seems you are having problems putting this together. This function, taken from the question I link to above, converts from byte array to hex string:

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
  StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
  foreach (byte b in ba)
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
  return hex.ToString();
}
```

Call it like this:

```
string hex = ByteArrayToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(myfloat));
```

---

And in comments you state that you wish to reverse the bytes. You can find out how to do that here: [How to reverse the order of a byte array in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784365/how-to-reverse-the-order-of-a-byte-array-in-c)

Comment: No, i need to convert the float to hex

Comment: I know. That's clear from your question title. And you just need to follow the steps in my answer.

Comment: would you please show me a piece of code that applies to your answer i am not that good dealing with bytes

Comment: OK, I did that. But I do believe that you could have done so yourself. Did you click on the link in my answer?

Comment: Okay i did it BitConverter.GetBytes(831.00001);
            string hex = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes((float)893.0001));
now the result is 02-40-5F-44 i want to get it reversed and w/o the dashes (445F4002)

Comment: Did you read my answer yet? Did you read the code in it? If you want to reverse the bytes, reverse the bytes.