# How to Convert IEEE-754 Floating-Point Conversion From Decimal Floating-Point To 32-bit Hexadecimal C#

Tags: c#

How to Convert IEEE-754 Floating-Point Conversion From Decimal Floating-Point To 32-bit Hexadecimal ?
Example : 75 Decimal Floating-Point = 42960000 hex decimal.

Comment: How about `string.Join("", BitConverter.GetBytes(75f).Reverse().Select(b => b.ToString("X2")))` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting IEEE 754 float to hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064230/converting-ieee-754-float-to-hex-string)

Comment: Or in .Net 5 use `BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen which is fine until someone uses an other-endian machine (and it is a very expensive way of doing it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Buffers.Binary;

float value = 75;
var bytes = new byte[sizeof(float)]; // could also use stackalloc here, but 
                                     // would need to do the x2 convert manually
BinaryPrimitives.WriteSingleBigEndian(bytes, value);
var hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes); // lazy way of getting hex
Console.WriteLine(hex);
```

You can also use `BitConverter` to get the bytes, but then you need to be aware of CPU-endianness:

```cs
using System;

float value = 75;
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(bytes);
var hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes); // lazy way of getting hex
Console.WriteLine(hex);
```

or zero-alloc:

```cs
using System;
using System.Buffers.Binary;

float value = 75;
Span<byte> bytes = stackalloc byte[sizeof(float)]; 
BinaryPrimitives.WriteSingleBigEndian(bytes, value);
const string hex = "0123456789abcdef";
foreach (var b in bytes)
{
    Console.Write(hex[(b >> 4) & 0b1111]); // hi
    Console.Write(hex[b & 0b1111]); // lo
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In .Net 5.0+ and .Net Core 2.0+ you can use `BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits`

```
var hex = BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits(myfloat).ToString("X");
```

There is also `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` for `double`